# Forcing a thread context switch

Tags: c, pthreads

I would like to be able to force a context switch from one thread to another. Therefore, I have implemented the following locking procedure:

```
#define TRUE  (1==1)
#define FALSE (0==1)

#include <pthread.h>

int acquire(void);
int release(void);
int c_yield(int count);

// Who was the last to acquire the lock
static volatile pthread_t lock_owner;

// Is the lock currently taken
static volatile int lock_taken = FALSE;

/* This variable indicates how many threads are currently waiting for
 * the lock. */
static volatile int lock_wanted = 0;

/* Mutex for protecting access to lock_wanted, lock_owner and
 * lock_taken */
static pthread_mutex_t mutex;

/* Condition even to notify when the lock becomes available */
static pthread_cond_t cond;

void init_lock(void) {
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
}

int acquire(void) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if(lock_taken) {
        lock_wanted++;
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        lock_wanted--;
    } 
    if(lock_taken) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        return EPROTO;
    } 
    lock_taken = TRUE;
    lock_owner = pthread_self();
    return pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int release(void) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    lock_taken = FALSE;
    if(lock_wanted > 0) {
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    }
    return pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Using another method (not shown), I can then implement a yield() that only returns if there are either no threads waiting for the lock, or after at least one other thread had a chance to run.

This implementation works fine most of the time, but if I stress-test it with ~50 threads  trying to acquire and release the lock in random intervals, every once in a while acquire() will return `EPROTO`, indicating that someone called `pthread_cond_signal` without setting first `lock_taken = FALSE`.

Why is that? It seems as if the CPU sometimes doesn't see the new value of `lock_taken`, which is why I already made the variables volatile. But it's still happening...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(lock_taken) {
    lock_wanted++;
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    lock_wanted--;
}
```

This should be `while(lock_taken)`, not `if`. There are several reasons you might wake from `pthread_cond_wait` but find the lock taken by another thread by the time you get scheduled. One is if there's a spurious wakeup. The other is if another thread enters `acquire` after we block, finds the lock not taken, and takes it itself before this thread gets the mutex again.

The canonical way would be:

```
lock_wanted++;
while(lock_taken) pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
lock_wanted--;
```

Get rid of all the `volatile`s, they harm performance and are not needed. Because mutexes are sufficient synchronization, nothing else is necessary. (And, to anyone else looking at your code, they signal that you don't understand thread synchronization and tried to 'sprinkle them in' until it just happened to work.)

Comment: Thanks! I see the point with another thread entering `acquire` before the waiting thread has had a chance to grab the freed lock. However, are there any other reasons for the "spurious wakeups" you mentioned? *pthread_cond_signal(3)* says that it's waking exactly one thread. In my defense: I did not believe that the `volatile` are required, but I sprinkled them in in case I'm wrong :-).

Comment: The same problem you have with `acquire` can occur *inside* the pthreads library itself in ways you can't control. Because the pthreads library has no access to the predicate, it can't internally use a `while` loop. So it has the same problem you do, but it has no way to fix it.

Comment: So *pthread_cond_signal(3)* is just plain wrong? The description there does not seem to allow for the possibility you describe (but I've also found several other questions and a wikipedia article on spurious wakeups, so I tend to believe you).

Comment: See [man 3p pthread_con_signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html). Posix man pages are way more complete and usually have an insightful rationale section

Comment: The `pthread_cond_signal` function could be implemented (though it would be a lousy implementation) just by calling `pthread_cond_broadcast`. [Spurious wakeups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) are explicitly permitted. While `pthread_cond_signal` wakes one thread, nothing at all may also wake a thread. (And, as you see, it's basically impossible to prevent them without testing state, and POSIX condition variables are stateless.) The extra overhead of avoiding them in the POSIX library is considerable. The extra overhead of handling them in the application is generally zero.